# Omit 'e+' suffix on a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

Sometimes numbers are displayed like this: `7.92436555894648e+29`. How can I display them in full?

Comment: Use a custom number format function, rather that relying on the default to string conversion ;-)

Comment: What exactly does this number represent?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it. I'll use a third-party BigNumber library. Thanks.